# Swift Playground with async/await "cannot find 'async' in scope"

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-playground, xcode13, swift5

I'm trying to run this async function on Xcode Playground:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case invalidServerResponse
    case invalidCharacterSet
}

func getJson() async throws -> String {
        let url = URL(string:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                  throw NetworkingError.invalidServerResponse
              }
        
        guard let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw NetworkingError.invalidCharacterSet
        }
        
        return result
}
    
let result = try! await getJson()
print(result)
```

and I'm receiving this error message:

```
error: ForecastPlayground.playground:27:25: error: 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency
let result = try! await getJson()
                        ^
```

So I tried to create am async block in my func call:

```
async{
    let result = try! await getJson()
    print(result)
}
```

And then I received this error message:

```
Playground execution failed:

error: ForecastPlayground.playground:27:1: error: cannot find 'async' in scope
async{
^~~~~
```

I tried to annotated my function with the new @MainActor attribute and it doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an import to `_Concurrency` (underscore because this is supposed to be included by default) or a library that makes use of the library, such as `UIKit` or `SwiftUI`.
It appears that Swift Playgrounds don't have access to all concurrency features at the moment though, such as `async let`.

**In summary**

```swift
import _Concurrency
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 13, to use `async` and `await` in a Playground, just import Foundation and wrap the code in a detached task.

```
import Foundation

Task.detached {
    func borat() async -> String {
        await Task.sleep(1_000_000_000)
        return "great success"
    }

    await print(borat())
}
```

And this is because there are only 3 places your code can call asynchronous functions: (1) in the body of an asynchronous function or property; (2) in the static `main()` method of a class, structure, or enumeration that’s marked with `@main`; (3) in a detached child task.